Missing HFP/HSP via ssh and terminal
When I log in via SSH and connect to the Bluetooth headset via terminal, I can only set the A2DP profile.
Also when I log in through the GUI and connect to the headset via the bluetooth manager, I only see the A2DP profile.
But when I log in through the GUI, restart wireplumber, and then connect my headset via terminal or bluetooth manager, I can set the HFP/HSP profile and the microphone and headphones work fine.
I would like to be able to set up an HFP/HSP profile via ssh and terminal, without logging in via GUI.  Is it possible?
